# How to convert documents to Base64

Tags: 2013, column, document-converter

It would be awesome if we could convert documents (word, excel, PDF, images) to base64 and then store the value in a column. I would love to automate this if possible.
I know it is possible with flow, but we are on SharePoint 2013 on premise.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, i was able to do this with Nintex Workflow using one of the community member's farm solution.
[Vadim Tabakman's list attachment to Base64 conversion farm solution](http://www.vadimtabakman.com/nintex-workflow-get-list-item-attachment-in-base64-custom-action-happy-thanksgiving.aspx)

Comment: I don't know if that's what you were looking for but, IMHO storing the file twice (or more, depending on your versioning configuration) could eat a lot of space. I would suggest you creating a service or a web handler to perform this transformation in real time. Depending on your needs, this could save a lot of storing space and not require recalculation where the document/file gets updated.